# What's the difference between a conventional index mutual fund and a non-conventional index mutual fund?

Tags: mutual-funds, index-fund, terminology

I read the term "*conventional* index mutual funds" in several places.

E.g., https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/faqs:

> Similar to **conventional index mutual funds**, most ETFs try to track an index, such as the S&P 500.

and :

https://www.heraldtribune.com/story/news/2014/04/26/of-index-funds-is-mutual-fund-or-etf-best-for-you/29243742007/

> I believe most investors will have better long-term performance investing in either **conventional index mutual funds** or ETFs associated with well-known indexes than they would with the majority of actively traded mutual funds or ETFs.

What's the difference between a conventional index mutual fund and a non-conventional index mutual fund?

Comment: The context in both cases makes it clear that the contrasting category is ETFs

Comment: When talking about any subcategory of things, the term "conventional" is often used in marketing to mean "other", while attempting to imply that the thing being talked about is exciting and innovative and the others are not.

Comment: @AakashM I didn't know that ETF is a type of mutual funds, and couldn't infer it from the two quotes. The question and the answers are interesting, at least to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term "conventional" refers to the *mutual fund*, distinguishing ETFs from "conventional" funds, whether they track an index or not. This is because an ETF *is* a type of mutual funds, it just trades differently (among other things) than "traditional" or "conventional" funds that only trade (and are priced) after the end of the trading day.

So a better distinction might be "Index ETFs" and "Index-tracking conventional mutual funds".

Comment: ETFs are really a type of mutual fund, hence the author’s tendency to refer to non-ETF mutual funds as “conventional.”

Comment: @BenMiller-RememberMonica I think you're right, and have made that more explicit.

Answer (score 4):

> What's the difference between a conventional index mutual fund and a
> non-conventional index mutual fund?

There are multiple flavors of funds. A conventional fund is a non-ETF one. Since ETFs are newer, the non-ETF ones are sometimes labeled conventional. We see the same type of confusion with IRAs: is it better to call the non-Roth one, non-Roth, or traditional?

Conventional or ETF can also be subdivided into active or passive. Where the passive ones are following an index.

Comment: If there are no unconventional **mutual** funds, then “Conventional mutual fund” seems pretty redundant”.